# How to map the result of stored procedure in C# with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns the following data:

[image: 1]

And here I execute the stored procedure in service:

```
 var result = await dbContext.SqlQueryAsync(@$"
                EXEC [dbo].[spCheckOver] 
                                 @roomId = {roomId},
                                 @startDate = '{startDate}',             
                                 @endDate = '{endDate}'");
```

When I hover over the result, it seems that it is empty.

What am I missing? How can I map that result to a model?

PS: The stored procedure is executed for sure because my first thought was that it isn't executed.

Comment: Read the docs: [Raw SQL Queries - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#basic-raw-sql-queries) or [Raw SQL Queries - EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql)

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: EF5 but i managed to solved this issue with the docs provided above. thanks!